# rm to remove a dir, any symlinks, AND symlink destinations?

Tags: rm, ln

I have two directories: `/all/origins/` & `/all/links/`.

Everything in `links/` points individually to something in `origins/`, but not everything in `origins/` is linked in `links/`. (Squares, rectangles & categorical hierarchy, get it?) *These are symlinks (`ln -s`), not hard links.*

Everything in 1. `links/` needs to be deleted, along with 2. the symlink destinations in `origins/` (not knowing whether they are in `origins/`), and 3. the `links/` directory itself.

What ***`rm` Unix command*** should I type to remove both the entire `links/` directory AND any symlinked destinations symlinked to in `origins/`?

I'm looking for something maybe like: `rm -R /all/links` or `rm -r --follow-all-ln /all/links`.

If an `rm` command with parameters will not do the job, please say so explicitly as that is my preference and implicit in the title (can Unix & Linux do this via `rm` without a `do` loop?—*only* if that won't work, then please state so and explain what `do` loop.)

Comment: In third line I think you want to say `links/` instead of `origins/`.

Comment: Possible and related, but not coterminous. My question is about removing the directory itself and such links with it. This near-dup removes only a file and only one at a time, specifically. But, it is related, so thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First take backup of your data in case something goes wrong.

What I understood is that you want to delete all the contents of `/all/links/` directory and the file to which the links inside this directory are pointing.

*There is no way to do this with a simple Unix command as you preferred, but it will work with a simple script.*

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in /all/links/*
do
rm  "$(readlink -f $i)"
rm "$i"
done

rmdir /all/links
```

As you said that all files inside `/all/links/` are symbolic links so there is no need to check each value of `i` whether it is a link or not.

Comment: Is there no way to do this with a simple Unix command? If so, I accept this as the answer and please approve my edit.

Comment: @JesseSteele the script is short enough that you could write it in a single line of shell... `for f in /all/links/*; do rm "$(readlink -f $f)"; rm "$f"; done; rmdir /all/links`. If you need it possibly more than once... go for the script as script.

Comment: Thank you, make it an answer and I will up vote it for usefulness, but, honestly, it is still not a simple Unix command (part of the question), but a script on a single line

Comment: @JesseSteele actually I replaced your edit `rm -R /all/links` with `rmdir /aa/links` because `rm $i` is deleting every file, so after the for loop the directory will be empty and there is no need to use recursion.

Comment: That is incorrect because there may be files other than links in the dir to be deleted, which was vague in the OP, but possible. Is all that ok? I don't want to edit the OP for this, to avoid the #chameleon thing.

Comment: @JesseSteele Your question said "Everything in `links/` points [...]".  But if there are also regular files in there, the first `rm` will delete them, the second will print an error, and the directory will still be empty by the time `rmdir` runs.

Comment: Guys, make it and editi it how you like. I should have said "may have other files" in the deleted dit, but I didn't and I won't change it. So, stick to how I worded it and I will accept it. If you all agree that rmdir is the way, with what I wrotr, not my unwritten, imaginary meaning, great, do as you deem best. It all helped solve my problem and does answer my OP. Thanks a ton!